# Reading text from a file using fscanf()

Tags: c, file, scanf, feof

guys i want to read the text from my file and assign every character to a single element of the array

```
char A[1000];

FILE * fpointer;
fpointer=fopen("text.txt","r");

i=0;
while(!feof(fpointer))
{
    fscanf(fpointer,"%c",&A[i]);
    i=i+1;
}

fclose(fpointer);

for (i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    printf("%c",A[i]);
}

return 0;
```

but the problem is that the output is some weird symbols instead of the file's text which is "This is just a test".Why is that happening ?

Comment: ye sorry forgot to include it :D. char A[1000];
i is also defined as int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible reasons include:

1. `fopen` failed to open the specified file. Fix by checking the return value of `fopen`.
2. See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/3049655)
3. You always print 100 characters, but if the file contains less than 100 characters, you're in trouble because you print uninitialized locations of the array, leading to UB. Fix by printing everything starting from zero upto `i`.

Corrected code snippet:

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
char A[1000];

FILE* fpointer;
fpointer = fopen("text.txt", "r");
if(!fpointer)
{
    fputs("fopen failed! Exiting...\n", stderr);
    exit(-1); /* Requires `stdlib.h` */
}

while(fscanf(fpointer, "%c", &A[i]) != EOF)
{
    i = i + 1;
}

fclose(fpointer);
for (j = 0; j < i; j++){
    printf("A[%d] = '%c'\n", j, A[j]);
}
```

Comment: adding a int variable k made it happen 
        while(!feof(fpointer)){
            fscanf(fpointer,"%c",&A[i]);
            i=i+1;
            k=i;
and then instead of 100 i use k Seems to be working . Thanks !!!

Comment: Yes. That'll work too. But make sure you take care of point 1 & 2 in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the [points by @Cool Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37086356/1170207):

In case your files do not contain the [null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), you can avoid using another variable to store the number of characters read. If you null terminate your read in characters, you can just print them directly as a string.

You have to make sure that A can hold enough characters. If you expect at most 1000 characters, make sure that A has a size of 1001 bytes to contain the terminating NUL character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char A[1001] = { 0 }; /* init to NUL, expect at most 1000 chars */
    int i;    
    FILE *fpointer;

    fpointer=fopen("text.txt","r");
    if(!fpointer) {
        perror("Error opening file"); /* print error message */
        exit(-1); /* Requires `stdlib.h` */
    }
    /* read all characters from fpointer into A */
    for (i=0; fscanf(fpointer, "%c", &A[i]) != EOF; i++);
    fclose(fpointer);

    printf("%s\n",A); /* print all characters as a string */

    /* alternatively, loop until NUL found */
    for (i=0; A[i]; i++)
        printf("%c", A[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```